# Calling a Stored Procedure properly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's my Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE facturar(codigo int(6),fecha date,cedula VARCHAR(9),cantidad int(3),peso VARCHAR(10),precio varchar(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE P float;
Declare total float;
set P=0;
set total=0;
insert into factura VALUES(ID,fecha,cedula,cantidad, peso, `precio`);
set P=peso*4;
if P between 2000 and 10000 then SET precio= (P*0.05)+(P*0.12)+P;
elseif P > 10000 then set precio= (P*0.05)+(P*0.10)+(P*0.12)+P;
else set precio= (P*0.12)+P;
end if;
set total = precio;
select  concat("Total de envio=", total);
END;
//
```

When i make the call:

```
call facturar (NULL,'2016/01/13', 'v18834415', '2', '96400', '');
```

It shows the result:

```
Total de envió=489712
```

But, once I take a look at the table the "precio" is in white while the other values are filled.

Comment: You should always list the columns when using `insert`.

Comment: Thanks Will for the edtion, looks a lot better indeed, also, would be nice if you know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute insert query after setting the value.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE facturar(codigo int(6),fecha date,cedula VARCHAR(9),cantidad int(3),peso VARCHAR(10),precio varchar(10))
BEGIN
DECLARE P float;
Declare total float;
set P=0;
set total=0;

set P=peso*4;
if P between 2000 and 10000 then SET precio= (P*0.05)+(P*0.12)+P;
elseif P > 10000 then set precio= (P*0.05)+(P*0.10)+(P*0.12)+P;
else set precio= (P*0.12)+P;
end if;
set total = precio;
select  concat("Total de envio=", total);
insert into factura VALUES(ID,fecha,cedula,cantidad, peso, total);
END;
//
```

use **total** variable in insert query instead of backquoted value

Comment: okay, i dont know how that worked, but it did, thanks a lot, also your answer was pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `precio` as a column in the `insert`.  Then you do some calculations, and never do anything with the values.

I strongly encourage two of things:

- indicate the difference between variables and columns by using a prefix for variables
- list all columns for `insert`

In your case, I think you need to move the insert after you set `precio`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE facturar(
    in_codigo int(6),
    in_fecha date,
    in_cedula VARCHAR(9),
    in_cantidad int(3),
    in_peso VARCHAR(10),
    in_precio varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @P float;
    Declare @total float;
    set @P = 0;
    set @total = 0;
    set @P = in_peso*4;
    if @P between 2000 and 10000 then SET in_precio= (@P*0.05)+(@P*0.12)+@P;
    elseif @P > 10000 then set in_precio= (@P*0.05)+(@P*0.10)+(@P*0.12)+@P;
    else set in_precio = (@P*0.12)+@P;
    end if;
    set @total = in_precio;
    insert into factura( . . . )
        VALUES(in_ID, in_fecha, in_cedula, in_cantidad, in_peso, in_precio);
    select concat('Total de envio=', @total);
END;
```

Comment: so to set "precio", i need "peso", that i will insert AFTER i did all the calculations?

Comment: okay, i dont know how that worked, but it did, thanks a lot, this answer was kinda hard to understand.